# streaming multiple output lines from a single input line using Clojure data.csv

Tags: clojure

I am reading a csv file, processing the input, appending the output to the input and writing the results an output csv. Seems pretty straight-forward. I am using **Clojure data.csv**. However, I ran into a nuance in the output that does not fit with anything I've run into before with Clojure and I cannot figure it out. The output will contain 0 to N lines for each input, and I cannot figure out how to stream this down to the calling fn.

Here is the form that is processing the file:

```
(defn process-file
  [from to]
  (let [ctr (atom 0)]
    (with-open [r (io/reader from)
                w (io/writer to)]
      (some->> (csv/read-csv r)
               (map #(process-line % ctr))
               (csv/write-csv w)))))
```

And here is the form that processes each line (that returns 0 to N lines that each need to be written to the output csv):

```
(defn process-line
  [line ctr]
  (swap! ctr inc)
  (->> (apps-for-org (first line))
       (reduce #(conj %1 (add-results-to-input line %2)) [])))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "and I cannot figure out how to stream this down to the calling fn"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, `csv/write-csv` within `process-file` writes what it is returned from the `reduce` in `process-line`, which is:

`[[v1a] [v1b] [v1c]....]`

instead of 

`[v1a]`\n
`[v1b]`\n
`[v1c]`

And I do not know how to return from the `reduce` so that `csv/write-csv` could write one line for each entry in the vector returned from the `reduce` in `process-line`.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to run `write-csv` for each value returns by the previous `map`? Replace that write call with `(mapv #(csv/write-csv w %))`, or use `doseq` to be more proper, although it doesn't thread well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. Thank you. That did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I didn't fully understand your question, but from your comment, I seem to have answered it.

If you want to run `csv/write-csv` for each row returned, you could just map over the rows:

```
(some->> (csv/read-csv r)
         (map #(process-line % ctr)) 
         (mapv #(csv/write-csv w %))))
```

Note my use of `mapv` since you're running side effects. Depending on the context, if you used just `map`, the laziness may prevent the writes from happening.

It would be arguably more correct to use `doseq` however:

```
(let [rows (some->> (csv/read-csv r)
                    (map #(process-line % ctr)))]

  (doseq [row rows] 
    (csv/write-csv w row)))
```

`doseq` makes it clear that the intent of the iteration is to carry out side effects and not to produce a new (immutable) list.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post an answer last night. I posted that comment as I was falling asleep. Arguably, I shouldn't have even checked my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're running into is that your `map` function `process-line` returns a collection of zero-to-many rows, so when you `map` over the input lines you get a collection of collections, when you just want one collection (of rows) to send to `write-csv`. If that's true, the fix is simply changing this line to use `mapcat`:

```
(mapcat #(process-line % ctr))
```

`mapcat` is like `map`, but it will "merge" the resulting collections of each `process-line` call into a single collection.